# Increase width of search bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap on a site. The search bar appears fine on large screens but for mobile phones, the search bar has an empty space in it. Please suggest me how can I increase the width of the search bar. Thanks.

[image]

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 donate_search">
    <span class="col-xs-12 donate_span">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" > 
    <img class="donate" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();  ?>/images/donate.png"> Donate Now
    </a>
    </span>

    <span class="col-xs-12">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form input-group " action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
    <input type="search" class="search-field form-control" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-white search-submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </span>
    </form>
    </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write below css in your specific media query :

```
button.search-submit {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.search-form label {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for your reply Fahad Uddin.

Answer (score 0):

Set `form > label{width: 100%;}`, though don't know why you put input in label